# Determine if Magento module is enabled

Tags: php, magento, module

What is the best way to determine if a particular module is enabled/active in Magento?  I've tried using `class_exists` to check if my code has been loaded and parsed by PHP but lately I've noticed its pretty unreliable (returns `true` even when I delete the module's .xml configuration).

Is there a core function I can call?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you would like to use a build in function just use

```
Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled(<module name>);
```

It is implemented in

```
Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
```

Comment: actually you should mention that module name sould be equal to : **MyCompany_MyModule**

Comment: Just fyi, this method was introduced to magento in CE 1.4.1.0, for lower version compatibility use the ```getModuleConifg``` solution

Answer (score 39):

Here's another option that is a more elegant way of finding out the status:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('modulename')->is('active', 'true')
```

Comment: I really like this method, it's very simple yet elegant. Thanks!